# getOwnPropertyNames includes a property name that hasownproperty returns false for

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Using chrome, on an about:blank page in the console:

`Object.hasOwnProperty(window, "performance")` returns false.

Yet, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)` returns an array containing performance.

Even, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "performance")` works and returns `{"enumerable": true,"configurable": true}`

Im not sure why this is occurring, or how to recreate it. I looked at the Mozilla docs for each of these functions and nothing explained this behavior.

Comment: it has something to do with inheritance,because hasOwn() returns true,strange,from where the window object can inherit properties ?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. If you try `window.hasOwnProperty("performance")` you will see that it returns `true`. Or maybe you meant `Object.hasOwn(window, "performance")`?